# Kafka Streams state store get operation fetches nothing even though change log topic shows a value

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a persistent key value store added to my topology. Without going into too much details, I will explain the part where I am facing an issue. I want to query the state store.

When I receive a tombstone record, I need to query the store to find if there is a corresponding entry for the key being deleted. I use the get call on the store to achieve that

```
store.get(key)
```

However, the get operation does not get anything, even though there is an entry for that key. I know that there is an entry since I can search for that key in the corresponding changelog topic (of the state store).

Any pointers to understand why this is happening ? How is the store on disk not in sync with the change log topic? How does it normally sync ?

Answer (score 1):

When sending a null value(tombstone) for a given key, the key will be deleted immediately from the state store table(the DB table) but it will not be deleted immediately from the change log topic.

The needed time for the deletion of the records from the change log topic after receiving a tombstone depends on some different factors like : Commit Intervals, Compaction Settings, Replication Latency and the Consumer Processing.

Even it will not be deleted immediately from the topic, the tombstones will not be shown in the stream processing flow when using the Kafka streams operations as "filter, map ...".